# is it appropriate to ask for product details?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

If one were to discover a product online (not viewable at LBS) and, before purchasing, wanted to check very specific details about it that the manufacturer and reviewers did not provide (or which one's search-fu had failed to locate), would it be appropriate to ask on stackexchange?

This sort of thing:

- Does the M-Wave Ada S III bottle cage adapter fit on the rails of a Brooks B17 saddle?
- Does the head of the Moon Aiolos Gauge MFP pump fit between the spokes of Brompton wheels with 32-hole rims?
- Are the side-pockets of a Carradice Super C saddlebag suitable for carrying standard water bottles?
- Is the cage of the MKS Esprit pedal interchangeable with the MKS Lambda and/or Gamma?

Answer (score 3):

Our "community specific off topic" reason is

> Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in The Velodrome.

That means shopping questions are off topic - like "do I buy brand X bottle holder or brand Y"

Instead, "what are the reasons one might buy a carbon bottle holder over a plastic or metal one" would be acceptable because its long-term useful and will mention features and downsides which can be applied to other situations.

Your example questions are not shopping, they are precise questions about specific items but **would be on-topic, in my opinion**.   Being so specific may reduce the number of answers because fewer people have exactly that combination of items.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the high-specificity and had debated including a related(?) query: Would aggregrating such questions be more or less appropriate? So, perhaps posting one question that included six queries about different aspects of the pump that weren't easily discoverable from marketing blurb, say? (Presumably, anyone able to answer one question about the product would be able to answer most/all of them.) Or might that be straying into product reviews in disguise?

Comment: @jhnc The title for the [tour] says "Bicycles is a question and answer site for people who ride, repair, or build bicycles."   So if the question is asked with the intent of riding, its on topic.  If the question is asked like a scammy astroturfing attempt, that's obvious and will get closed pretty quick.   Being specific and focused is totally okay.

Comment: Even without specific problems mentioned, there's so much out of date material and opinion on this site that pops up from time to time, it's easy to question the point of the rule other than in the case of reducing volume of questions.